# Error in Bootstrap navbar responsive. why isn't this code working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[image: Here are my responsive template]

But my side menu is giving this error. What can it be?
Note: I'm working with two menus, one main and one side, but the main is ok. 
I'm a little lost in this part of the code, can help me?

This is the part of the menu that is giving problem.

**My Bootstap**

```
<!-- MENU LATERAL -->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="hero">
            <div id="vertical" class="verticalmenu ttmenu dark-style ">
               <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"></div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li class="dropdown ttmenu-full">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">TABBED<b class="dropme"></b></a>
                        <ul id="first-menu" class="dropdown-menu vertical-menu">
                           <li>
                              <div class="ttmenu-content">
                                 <div class="tabbable row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                          <li class="active"><a href="#tabs5-pane1" data-toggle="tab">Rich Features</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="#tabs5-pane2" data-toggle="tab">Thumbnail</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="#tabs5-pane3" data-toggle="tab">Carousel</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="#tabs5-pane4" data-toggle="tab">Embed Video</a></li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end col-md-3 -->
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                       <div class="tab-content">
                                          <div id="tabs5-pane1" class="tab-pane active">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <div class="box">
                                                      <ul>
                                                         <li>
                                                            <h4>FONT ICON SUPPORT</h4>
                                                         </li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Web Design <span class="fa fa-laptop"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Web Development <span class="fa fa-gears"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Graphic Design <span class="fa fa-leaf"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">IOS & ANDROID <span class="fa fa-android"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Logo Design <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Mockup Design <span class="fa fa-maxcdn"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">e-Commerce <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Digital Marketing <span class="fa fa-desktop"></span></a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">SEO Services <span class="fa fa-area-chart"></span></a></li>
                                                      </ul>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end box -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <div class="box">
                                                      <ul>
                                                         <li>
                                                            <h4>WHY CHOOSE TT MENU</h4>
                                                         </li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Responsive Layout</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Retina Display Ready</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Tons of Icons</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Gradient Colors</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Beginner Friendly</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Detailed Documentation</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">100% Bootstrap Base</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">HTML5 CSS3</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">And Much More...</a></li>
                                                      </ul>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end box -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <img src="images/darkmenubg.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                             </div>
                                             <!-- end row -->
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="tabs5-pane2" class="tab-pane">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 menu-image">
                                                   <div class="widget clearfix">
                                                      <a href="#">
                                                         <div class="entry">
                                                            <img src="images/menu_mini_01.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            <span class="magnifier"></span>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- enntry -->
                                                      </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end widget -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4 menu-image">
                                                   <div class="widget clearfix">
                                                      <a href="#">
                                                         <div class="entry">
                                                            <img src="images/menu_mini_02.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            <span class="magnifier"></span>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- enntry -->
                                                      </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end widget -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4 menu-image">
                                                   <div class="widget clearfix">
                                                      <a href="#">
                                                         <div class="entry">
                                                            <img src="images/menu_mini_03.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            <span class="magnifier"></span>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- enntry -->
                                                      </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end widget -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                   <div class="widget clearfix">
                                                      <a href="#">
                                                         <div class="entry">
                                                            <img src="images/menu_mini_04.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            <span class="magnifier"></span>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- enntry -->
                                                      </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end widget -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                   <div class="widget clearfix">
                                                      <a href="#">
                                                         <div class="entry">
                                                            <img src="images/menu_mini_05.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            <span class="magnifier"></span>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- enntry -->
                                                      </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end widget -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                   <div class="widget clearfix">
                                                      <a href="#">
                                                         <div class="entry">
                                                            <img src="images/menu_mini_06.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            <span class="magnifier"></span>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- enntry -->
                                                      </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end widget -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                             </div>
                                             <!-- end row -->
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="tabs5-pane3" class="tab-pane">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <div class="box">
                                                      <h4>ABOUT OUR COMPANY</h4>
                                                      <p>Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham de  Bonorum " are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
                                                      <p>Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" are also form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
                                                      <button class="btn btn-primary small" href="">Read more</button>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end box -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                         <div class="item active">
                                                            <a href="single-project.html"><img src="images/menu_01.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- End Item -->
                                                         <div class="item">
                                                            <a href="single-project.html"><img src="images/menu_02.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <!-- End Item -->
                                                      </div>
                                                      <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- /.carousel -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                             </div>
                                             <!-- end row -->
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="tabs5-pane4" class="tab-pane">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <div class="box">
                                                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mdfMT5Zi8Eo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end box -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                   <div class="box">
                                                      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/48401493?color=90cc62&title=0&byline=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <!-- end box -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                             </div>
                                             <!-- end row -->
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!-- tab-content --> 
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end col md-9 -->
                                 </div>
                                 <!-- end tabbable -->
                              </div>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class="dropdown ttmenu-full">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Grid <b class="dropme"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu vertical-menu">
                           <li>
                              <div class="ttmenu-content">
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <!-- end row -->
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                       <div class="coldesc">col</div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <!-- end row -->
                              </div>
                              <!-- end ttmenu-content -->
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <!-- end mega menu -->
                     <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="dropme"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu vertical-dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                           <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                           <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                              <a href="#">Sub Menu <span class="dropme-left"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                 <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                                 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#">Even More.. <span class="dropme-left"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                       <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- navbar-collapse collapse -->
</div>
```

Comment: Put a jsfiddle demo or at least some code or we can't help you

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Please note that a JSFiddle link by itself is insufficient. The code to reproduce the issue *must* be in the question.

Comment: I edit my code.